# Why does my Xbox One controller not work on Dark Souls 3 PC?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-3

I'm trying to play Dark Souls 3 on my PC and my controller is not detected at all. My controller is able to navigate Steam's Big Picture mode just fine, so I don't think this is a problem with my controller or the receiver. It works in other games as well. What can I do?

Comment: Dumb question -Have you got the latest drivers?

Comment: I do, it turns out the answer was something else

Comment: It's always the simple things :)

Comment: This problem is the same in every souls title... how can it be so hard to fix?

Comment: This actually happens in several different games. It's not a souls-only problem. It probably just results from developer naivete.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The game does not handle multiple controllers well, so another plugged in controller may be taking priority.

Make sure you unplug any other controllers/usb devices, like flight sticks, joysticks, USB cameras, USB keyboards, then restart the game.

Comment: Or anything that identifies as a "joystick", e.g. a G13 keypad...

Comment: or USB Camera!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by:

Going to Big picture mode > settings (cog icon) > controller settings > untick all except "guide button focuses steam"

Start the game and it works flawlessly.